# From which shastra is the story of a wife and her husband Kaushik who was visiting prostitutes?

Tags: puranas, dharma, women, smriti, itihasa

The story is mentioned [here in wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anasuya#The_Divine_Trinity_tests_Anasuya)

> A Brahmin named Kaushik from Pratishthan used to visit a prostitute, despite being a Brahmin and having a devoted wife.

It's also mentioned on other sites through google search, but none of them cite a purana or shastra.

Does anyone know which shastra this story is from?

Comment: Brahmin's wife here is not Anasuya.

Comment: @TheDestroyer According to wikipedia, her name was Anasuya. There were multiple women named Anasuya.

Comment: Same wikipedia which you quoted says his wife is not Anasuya. Read again properly.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Ok I see, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The story of Shandili and Kaushik is given in [Garuda Purana.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122622.html)

> Once on a time there lived in the city of Pratisthana, a leper Brahmana whose name was Kaushika. His wife, who was firmly devoted to
> him, used to adore and worship her lord as a god without even thinking
> for a moment that he was afflicted with such a foul and loathsome
> disease. But Kaushika was a cross and peevish husband, and never
> missed opportunities to abuse his wife, who, though often chastised,
> never ceased to pay him god-like veneration and love. One day,
> Kaushika took a fancy to visit a courtezan in the city, and expressed
> that desire to his wife. Whereupon she took him on her shoulders and
> safely carried him to that house of ill fame. Nor did she forget to
> take with her a considerable amount of money which the courtezan might
> ask for her nefarious trade.
>
> Now it happened that the Sage Mandavya was then undergoing punishment
> on the top of a pointed mace, as he was unjustly sentenced by the
> authorities on a false charge of theft. The faithful wife, on her way
> to the house of the courtezan, touched with her feet the body of that
> afflicted sage, who, in his agony, cursed her with the pangs of
> widowhood on the break of day. The wife, on the other hand, forbade
> the Sun to rise in order that the curse of the Sage might not take
> effect. The Sun-God, overpowered by the energy of conjugal chastity,
> was afraid to show his face, and creation was enshrouded in a pall of
> darkness. Ages past without the Sun in the sky.
>
> The frightened gods resorted to Brahma for help and advice. Brahma
> said,
>
> “It is the energy of Chastity that has overpowed the energy of
> asceticism, and obstructed the advent of the Sun. Go, ye gods, to
> Anasuya, and she will plead, on your behalf, to the wife of Kaushika.”
>
> The gods did as they were told to do. Anasuya saw and propitiated her
> with the boon of a long life and perfect health to her lord, and lo
> and behold, the Sun-God again appeared in the sky.